# how to show text after the text-overflow:ellipsis

Tags: html, css

Here is the example

```css
#div2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box
  <div class="test">here</div>
</div>
```

problem is the text "here" enclose in div element with class name test should be shown here and it should be after the three dots.

In this case, the text "here" is not show entirely. How to make it shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because entire content of div is truncated. That's why  `here` is not shown there.

You can try like:

```
<div id="div2">
  <div>
      This is some long text that will not fit in the box
  </div>
  <div class="test">here</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#div2 > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; 
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 4px;
}
```

and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aefcm16w/)

Comment: @anni does this really solve your issue ? ... there is a lot of problem with this answer, first he completely changed the structure. the test element is now outside and not affected with the width of parent ... there is the use of absolute without setting relative to parent .. the border wrap the elements seperately ... position absolute is not even considered because of specifity, etc, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I don't think that changing structure make this answer not acceptable. The CSS `absolute` is from OP maybe he/she has reason to do that. `position absolute is not even considered because of specifity` ?? Which specifity ?

Comment: i didn't say that it's not ok to change the structure, i simply comment on some problem ... you made the element outside the fixed widih and you also make it with fixed width [don't know why] and thus no more issue ... and for absolute simply check your code to understand : `#div2 > div` is more specific than `.test` so position absolute is not used.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your current HTML structure you can simply add some `padding-right` and set `right:0` to `test` element. You may notice that the value of padding right should take into consideration the content of test, so you have to adjust it if needed.

```css
#div2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  padding-right:25px;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box
  <div class="test">here</div>
</div>
```

By the way here is another way to do this without the use of absolute position:

```css
#div2 {
  width: 12em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
span {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <span>This is some long text that will not fit in the box</span>
  <div class="test">here</div>
</div>
```